# C# Powershell not returning any Get-ChildItem results

Tags: c#, powershell, model-view-controller

When I run powershell from my MVC application, i get no results from the `Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools` command.

If i run it directly in powershell it works fine. I have set the site to run on administrator account, thinking that maybe it cant "see" the pools, but no luck.

This is just a test too, accessing the pools, as what i was origionally struggling with was turning off an application pool, as it "could not be found". with `Get-WebAppPoolState -name $service`

```
 public static string test()
    { 
        using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        { 
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
                {
                    invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                    invoker.Invoke("Import-Module WebAdministration");

                    runspace.Open(); 
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace; 
                    powershell.AddScript(@"Import-Module WebAdministration 
                            Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools"); 
                    var results = powershell.Invoke();

                    var result = "";
                    result += ResultsToString(results); // results is a blank list
                    result += String.Join(",", powershell.Streams.Error.ToList().Select(x => x.Exception.Message));
                                           
                    return result;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Any ideas where the issue lies? code, permissions?

Comment: No errors? If you change your script to return something else, does it?

Comment: Retype the dash for the `-Path` parameter. Right now it is an [Em-Dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html), not a regular minus character

Comment: You probably aren't running VS as an admin.  Right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: thanks, i tried changing the dash, no luck. I can get errors yes. I get this if trying to access a pool `"Cannot find path 'IIS:\\AppPools\\MyPoolName' because it does not exist."` This is published to a server, not running in VS.

Comment: Ive added the same code to a WPF application and ran that on the server and it runs fine, getting all the app pool info. So wondering why an MVC application with the pool running as administrator , cannot "see" them. Ive also tried impersonation